# How is Block.one related to EOS? What is their history?

Tags: block.one

From what I know Block.one is the development company to help build out EOS. But what is the history of Block.one? How did Block.one win the rights to build out EOS vs another company? Were there other companies that were competing to build it out?

Answer (score 1):

> But what is the history of Block.one?

Block.one is a company registered in Cayman Islands founded on May 2017 after the first version of the EOSIO whitepaper was published by Dan Larimer (current CTO of Block.one.) The now-CEO of Block.one, Brendan Blumer, approached the now-CTO of Block.one, Dan Larimer, to discuss possible collaborations, and together they decided to build out EOSIO and Block.one. Dan Larimer had extensive prior experience in blockchain development, having involved himself in Bitcoin in the early days in 2009, having pioneered DPOS consensus, and having built what were the 2 most active blockchains in the space at that time in terms of on-chain transactions per day: BitShares and Steem. Thus, EOSIO is built on top of existing code from BitShares, leveraging Dan's technical experience on scalability and extensibility requirements.

> How did Block.one win the rights to build out EOS vs another company? Were there other companies that were competing to build it out?

The lead developer, author of the whitepaper, and the creator of the fundamental concepts of EOSIO is the CTO of Block.one, Dan Larimer, so they had a significant advantage in terms of being the most likely team capable of delivering the project, and the amount of funding raised showed that the market was fairly confident in Block.one's abilities. As far as I know, there was no one else attempting to build EOSIO, and the prevailing sentiment of the mainstream blockchain community as expressed by various public figures and public forums was mostly skepticism.

> How is Block.one related to EOS?

EOS mainnet uses the EOSIO software built by Block.one, so--at least for now--there is significant communication and collaboration between EOS community and Block.one, and Block.one attempts to assist them and other EOSIO-based blockchains with technical and government issues among others.